# Post Data to server using http post and get response true or false in android

Tags: java, android, json, http-post

I want to Post `EmailID` and `Password` using `AsyncTask` and get response True or false, how to do that. we are using `json`. I have seen some links but can't understand.
below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
private class GetLoginDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Please wait..", "Retrieving data ...", true);
        m_ProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
        m_ProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Simulates a background job.
        String mStrings[] = { "" };
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String postURL = "http://192.168.0.126/MeritServices/MeritService.svc/Login";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EmailID", strEmail));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", strPassword));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param, HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
            if (resEntity != null) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE :::: ", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("ERROR ::: ", e.toString());
        }
        return mStrings;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        System.out.println("ProgressBar Dismiss");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. you have the request content, the post, the asynctask, the result reading. what are you missing?

Comment: what u are getting in response from server?

Comment: your code seems just fine , what is the prob you are facing , share error or logcat

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid i got RESPONSE ::::(11135): ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Request Error</title>
<p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="http://192.168.0.126/MeritServices/MeritService.svc/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>

Comment: my attempt to make a dummy test fails i get connection refused to 192.168.0.126 , is there something i can give it a try ??

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid its LocalHost thats y. Sorry i dont have any other option for that. i dont know how to post emailID & Password to server using http post.can you help me by example. Thanks.

Comment: what response you are getting from server.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `resEntity` contains the content you are looking for, i.e. your JSON String.
You can access it by

```
InputStream inputStream = resEntity.getContent();
```

and then read the String. An example how this is done is here:
http://misha.beshkin.lv/httpresponse-entity-to-string/

However, if anything unexpected happened on the server side so that it doesn't return the JSON, you want to find that out before you access the Entity's content.
You can do that by checking the status code:

```
Integer responseCode = responsePOST.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

You can then check the response code. If it is 200, it's "OK", and everything went well. 404 is page not found, 500 is internal server error, and there are many more. Of course it also depends on the implementation of your server.
You can look up the definition of all status codes here:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Handling the status code is maybe sufficient for you, if you just want to know that your post succeeded and the server reponded "OK".